# Jena: How to retrieve name from DBPedia article

Tags: jena, apache-jena

I have a dbpedia URL `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chicago_Cubs` and want to use Apache Jena to parse this RDF and get the label of the page. It should be `Chicago Cubs`.

I tried to do

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
Resource teamModel = model.createResource(teamURLStrInDBPedia );
```

But the returned resource doesn't include any properties.

How could I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you may need to perform something like this.

```
        FileManager fManager = FileManager.get();
        fManager.addLocatorURL();
        Model model = fManager.loadModel("http://dbpedia.org/data/Chicago_Cubs.rdf");
```

The createResource function will not parse fetch and data, it will add a new resource to the model.

Cheers.